# Google Auth giving "Request had insufficient authentication scopes" error while trying to run Google Script

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, google-cloud-functions, google-authentication

I am trying to run my Google Script from within a cloud function from Firebase. When I run it, Google Auth is return an error saying `Request had insufficient authentication scopes`. I'm using the example from Google Quickstart found here: [Google Apps Script Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/nodejs#troubleshooting). My scope found in my token.json file is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects` Is there something else I need to include just to run my simple script? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably you need permission to make external requests. Adding any scope manually disables automatic scope detection. Review all methods used and their official documentation; it will state the required scopes for each method. Also, it is common to require a Drive scope.

Comment: @tehhowch Thank you! I added the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.deployments` scopes and it went past that issue. Thanks!